# Python cv2 outputs invalid video

Tags: python, opencv

System information

- OpenCV => 4.4.0.46
- Operating System / Platform => MacOS Catalina 10.15.4
- Compiler => Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda 4.8.3

I'm doing a computer vision task, in which my current step is to create a video based on previously created images. To do so, I'm using OpenCV like this:

```
fps = 25
files = natsorted([f for f in glob.glob(os.getcwd()+'/tf_files/test/*.jpg')])[:125]
size = (1920,1080)

fourcc = int(cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'))
out = cv2.VideoWriter('test.mp4',fourcc,fps=fps,frameSize=size)

for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    out.write(img)

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The files list returns the paths of the images:

```
files[0]
'/Users/XXX/XXX/projects/phase_seg/tensorflow-for-poets-2/tf_files/test/0.jpg'
```

with the size of each file being:

```
cv2.imread(files[0]).shape
>>> (1080, 1920, 3)
```

The code does not give any errors and does actually create a video called 'test.mp4'. Moreover, if the amount of images is changed, the video does change in size as well. I can also open the images with opencv without any problem.
However, the video cannot be played, and when exported to another program, it is of length 0. I've tried different variations of fourcc like 'M','P','4','V', but without any success. What can be a possible explanation for this?

Comment: hey, I'm not sure if this would help, but I can't tell why you used int() in fourcc for the codec, so can you just try without it and also try this instead  `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')`

Comment: Casting int() to the fourcc codec does not actually change anything, I just used it to test as a suggestion. Moreover, the fourcc(*'DIVX') does not work either.